# Dialogflow Webhook C# integration

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, webhooks, dialogflow-es

What is the Dialogflow webhook format? I want to capture the data in an MVC controller and then respond to the webhook whilst maintaining context. How do I do this in C# with the Dialogflow v2 client library? I haven't found any examples to follow in this language and am unsure how to capture the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read more about Dialogflow webhook format [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/v1/dialogflow-webhook). Regarding the Dialoglow v2 client library, it is specifically [stating](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/index.html#getting-started) that you don't need to use it and can answer in JSON instead using `JObject`.

If you want to use `Protobuf` to lower the overhead and save some traffic you will have to use utilities from idiomatic cloud libraries described in the previous link.

Comment: Thanks for this reference

Answer (score 3):

The "Dialogflow V2 client library" is for people who are writing clients that send *requests to* Dialogflow. Dialogflow calls this a "Detect Intent Request", since you're sending a text string (or audio stream) to Dialogflow and it will determine and process the Intent.

If you're interested in building a Fulfillment webhook that is called when an Intent is matched, then you want to look at the Dialogflow Fulfillment API, which is different. There is no supported library for C# yet, but you can parse and return the JSON. The JSON for V1 and V2 are slightly different (mostly in the names of the fields used, but also occasionally in what the values should be).

You can see the [fields for the JSON](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works) as well as [several examples](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json) of the request and response formats. There was also an article on Medium recently posted by a Google Developer Relations member discussing [using C# for fulfillment](https://medium.com/google-cloud/dialogflow-fulfillment-with-c-and-app-engine-18eb7db071de) in Dialogflow.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense now; I thought I was missing something. Thanks for the examples.

Comment: Glad it helps! I also added another reference to a recently posted article on C# and fulfillment. If these do help, upvoting the answer is appreciated.

Comment: I have another Dialogflow question directly related to webhooks here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538487/dialogflow-disable-google-assistant. If you do get a chance, I'd really appreciate some help with it :)